# awk exclude specific column from multicolumn lines

Tags: awk

How can I, using awk, exclude the columns that start with 300, but not excluding columns that have 300? For example

input:

```
100230070 100214996 100214992 300230217 100227462 100231344
100223007
100230055
300000213 300000180 100230295
100230295 100222531 100230174 100230051
```

output:

```
100230070 100214996 100214992 100227462 100231344
100223007
100230055
100230295
100230295 100222531 100230174 100230051
```

Comment: awk '
{
    for (i = 1; i <= $NF; i++)
        if($i != "300") {print $i}
}' 300_file.txt. Just to start. (I'm still looking for something like a ^)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following `awk` may help you here.

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/^300/){$i=""}};gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,FS);gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")} 1' Input_file
```

Adding a non-one liner form of solution too now.

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){
    if($i~/^300/){ $i="" }};
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,FS);
  gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")
}
1
'  Input_file
```

Explanation: Adding explanation too here.

```
awk '
{
  for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){                   ##Starting a for loop from variable i value 1 to till value of NF(number of fields) here.
    if($i~/^300/){ $i="" }};            ##Checking condition if a column starts with 300 then nullify its value.
  gsub(/[[:space:]]+/,FS);              ##Using gsub to substitute spaces all occurrences with a single space.
  gsub(/^[[:space:]]+|[[:space:]]+$/,"")##Uinsg gsub for replacing starting space and ending space with NULL.
}
1                                       ##Mentioning 1 to print the edited or non-edited line here.
' Input_file                            ##Mentioning Input_file name here.
```

Answer (score 3):

Using awk without any loop:

```
awk '{gsub("^(300[^ ]* )+|( 300[^ ]*)+","")}1' file
```

The unwanted number (that start with `300`) can be either at the start of the line or in middle of it. Several consecutive sequences of the at number can be removed (with `+` regex operator)

That can obviously be easily translated in `sed`:

```
sed -E 's/^(300[^ ]* )+|( 300[^ ]*)+//' file
```

Comment: I was trying to build this regex ... for sure the best solution yet.

Comment: This one seems to work too awk '{gsub("(^| )(300[^ ]*)+","")}1' or sed 's/^\| 300[^ ]*//g'

Comment: @ctac_ not exactly, there is an extra space at the beginning of the 4th line

Comment: You are right, test only with first line.With sed, need only to add s/^ *// at the end, but with awk, your answer is better.

Comment: @ctac_ To get rid of that extra space, rebuild the record with `$1=$1`, ie. `awk '{gsub("(^| )(300[^ ]*)+","");$1=$1}1' file`

Answer (score 2):

Give this awk one-liner a try:

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)sub(/^300.*/," ",$i)}
     1+gsub(/ +/," ")+sub(/^ /,"")' file
```

- the `sub()` function does regex based substitution, will replace all fields starting with `300` by empty string, this will leave empty spaces, the `FS`.
- the `gsub() and sub()` at end, will merge the empty spaces and make the output pretty.

Comment: almost. First line merges 2 columns: 100230070 100214996 100214992100227462 100231344

Comment: @JonyD now it should go.

Answer (score 2):

Another variant of `gsub`bing but with `FS` and `$1=$1` to remove leading `FS`s:

```
$ awk '{gsub("(^|" FS ")300[^" FS "]*","");$1=$1}1' file
100230070 100214996 100214992 100227462 100231344
100223007
100230055
100230295
100230295 100222531 100230174 100230051
```

Answer (score 1):

Another awk

```
awk '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i!~/^300/)printf "%s"$i FS};printf "%c","\n"}' infile
```

Print each field that do not start with 300